# Using the build-in streamWriter from the xmlbuilder package in nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml

I want to create XML files and for this I am using the package xmlbuilder.
The initial code works fine, which looks like following:

```
const xmlStructure = {
    // xml structure
};

const root = builder.create(xmlStructure, { encoding: 'utf-8' });

const xml = root.end({ pretty: true });

const readableStream = new Readable();
const writableStream = file.createWriteStream();

writableStream
    .on('error', error => {
        throw error;
     })

    .on('finish', async () => {
        // do something in the DB
    });

readableStream._read = () => {
    readableStream.push(xml);
    readableStream.push(null);
};

readableStream.pipe(writableStream);
```

but I saw in the wiki of the package, that there is a build in streamwriter.
I would like to add this to the project and remove some of the custom things I did in the code.

I tried the following approach:

```
const xmlStructure = {
    // xml structure
};

const writableStream = file.createWriteStream();

const writer = xmlbuilder.streamWriter(writableStream);

writableStream
    .on('error', error => {
        throw error;
    })

    .on('finish', async () => {
        // do something in the DB
    });


const root = builder.create(xmlStructure, { encoding: 'utf-8' });

const xml = root.end(writer);

const readableStream = new Readable();

readableStream.pipe(writableStream);
```

Unfortunatly this didn't work, what am I doing wrong or forgetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing line of code was the following:

```
writableStream.end();
```

So the end result looks like this:

```
const xmlStructure = {
    // xml structure
};

const root = builder.create(xmlStructure, { encoding: 'utf-8' });

const writableStream = file.createWriteStream();

const writer = xmlbuilder.streamWriter(writableStream);

const xml = root.end(writer);

writableStream.end();

writableStream
    .on('error', error => {
        throw error;
    })

    .on('finish', async () => {
        // do something in the DB
    });
```